# (IDAPython)How to get the function name string from the Function address?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

For example, in the Registers windows of IDA pro, It show the following.
( I think "WS2_32.dll:ws2_32_shutdown" is a string that IDA automatically resolved.)

EAX 766D32B0 WS2_32.dll:ws2_32_shutdown

So, would you please tell me how to get the function name string (such as WS2_32.dll:ws2_32_shutdown) from the Address (such as 766D32B0)  by IDAPython ?

I try to do the following, but it don’t show the function name string..

eax_adddress = idc.get_reg_value("EAX")
print("EAX-->%x" % eax_adddress)
print("FunctionName-->%s" % idc.get_func_name(eax_adddress))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduced to the minimum, this is how you get the name of a function and the module in Python 3:

```
import ida_funcs
import ida_nalt
import idc
import pathlib

reg_address = idc.get_reg_value('EAX') # or use the register relevant to your case
func_name = ida_funcs.get_func_name(reg_address)

# if you want to use the main image name:
#image_name = pathlib.Path(ida_nalt.get_input_file_path()).name

# if you want to use the segment from which the function is coming from:
image_name = idc.get_segm_name(reg_address)

print(f'{image_name}:{func_name}')
```

Please note that this probably works properly only in case you have multiple images in the same database. Otherwise `idc.get_segm_name` might actually return the actual segment name, not the image name.

You can easily rewrite that for Python 2 if needed by not utilizing the `pathlib` and change the `print()`-function to be a `print`-statement in case you want to access the original image file name.

Comment: I was able to get the name of the EXE file and function name by using the method you taught me, but I was not able to get the name of the DLL that exported the function. 
The output of your code was shown the following.
>malware.exe:ws2_32_shutdown

Comment: Sorry, your question wasn't clear to me in that regard. I edited my snippet, it should do what you're asking for now.

Comment: Hi new_turtle,  thank you so much for your great kindness ! Thank you.